# React: how to use spread operator in a function that toggles states?

Tags: reactjs, use-state, conditional-operator, togglebutton, spread

I made an example of my question here:
[EXAMPLE](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-usestate-on-individual-elements-qe025?fbclid=IwAR060nbQj46OXDl4q0j3wEY1kab8248PLybnBnsSFNVSBkrQ4YSfPa59khw&file=/src/App.js)

I'm mapping an array of objects that have a button that toggles on click, but when clicking on the button every object is changed.

This is the code

```
export default function App() {
  const [toggleButton, setToggleButton] = useState(true);

  // SHOW AND HIDE FUNCTION
  const handleClick = () => {
    setToggleButton(!toggleButton);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>SONGS</h1>
      <div className="container">
        {/* MAPPING THE ARRAY */}
        {songs.map((song) => {
          return (
            <div className="song-container" key={song.id}>
              <h4>{song.name}</h4>
              {/* ON CLICK EVENT: SHOW AND HIDE BUTTONS */}
              {toggleButton ? (
                <button onClick={handleClick}>PLAY</button>
              ) : (
                <button onClick={handleClick}>STOP</button>
              )}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I know I should be using spread operator, but I couldn't get it work as I spected.

Help please!

Comment: you have all of your buttons attached to the same state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course every object will change because you need to keep track of toggled state for each button. Here is one way to do it:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const songs = [
  {
    name: "Song A",
    id: "s1"
  },
  {
    name: "Song B",
    id: "s2"
  },
  {
    name: "Song C",
    id: "s3"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [toggled, setToggled] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    setToggled(
      toggled.indexOf(id) === -1
        ? [...toggled, id]
        : toggled.filter((x) => x !== id)
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>SONGS</h1>
      <div className="container">
        {songs.map((song) => {
          return (
            <div className="song-container" key={song.id}>
              <h4>{song.name}</h4>
              {toggled.indexOf(song.id) === -1 ? (
                <button onClick={() => handleClick(song.id)}>PLAY</button>
              ) : (
                <button onClick={() => handleClick(song.id)}>STOP</button>
              )}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

There are many ways to do it. Here, if an `id` is in the array it means that button was *toggled*.
You can also keep `id`s of toggled buttons in object for faster lookup.

Comment: Thanks! BTW How can I prevent multiple buttons to be toggled at the same time?... I mean: when a button is active, toggle to stop it when another button is clicked.

Comment: @AfxCrush Not sure if I got you but you seem to want to keep *only one id* inside the array at a time right? Change the `handleClick` correspondingly. Directly store id of clicked button if its not there instead of appending; instead of `[...toggled, id]` do `[id]`

Answer (score 1):

One way of handling this requirement is to hold local data into states within the Component itself.

I have created a new `Button` Component and manages the toggling effect there only. I have lifted the `state` and `handleClick` method to `Button` component where it makes more sense.

```
const Button = () => {
  const [toggleButton, setToggleButton] = useState(true);
  const click = () => {
    setToggleButton((prevValue) => !prevValue);
  };

  return <button onClick={click}>{toggleButton ? "Play" : "Stop"}</button>;
};
```

Working Example - [Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-usestate-on-individual-elements-forked-ix44t?file=/src/App.js:203-440)